# How make scrollable dropdown in foreignkey field Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I need to make the city field scrollable, how can I do this?
[image]

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from cities_light.models import City

# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user  = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.IntegerField(validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')], blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/')
    city  = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
     
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.user)
```

forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('user',)
```

edit_profile.html

```
<form  method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form userForm %}
    {% bootstrap_form profileForm %}
    {% buttons %}
      <button href="{% url 'accounts:profile' %}" type="submit" class='boxed-btn3 w-100'>Save</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

There any argument should add in Forignkey field or the html file should edit?

Comment: You need to make in frontend?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Select`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#select) widget to render a dropdown menu for a `ChoiceField` or `ModelChoiceField` in a Django form. It can be customized with various attributes and options, including the `size` attribute to control the number of visible options and make the dropdown scrollable, so in forms.py:

```py
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('user',)
        widgets = {
            'city': forms.Select(attrs={'size': 10})
        }
```

The `size` attribute is set to `10`, which will show `10` options at a time and make the dropdown scrollable, you can adjust it according to your need.

#### Edit

Try this in the template:

```html
{% bootstrap_form profileForm %}
<select id="{{ profileForm.city.id_for_label }}" name="{{ profileForm.city.name }}" class="form-select" size="10">
    {% for city in profileForm.city %}
        <option value="{{ city.value }}">{{ city.label }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, just when refresh the page it make scrollable for less than second and still work without scroll.

Comment: @OmniaOsman Try Edited Answer with template itself.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: @OmniaOsman What do exactly want, can you please clarify, I suppose the code provided should give a drop-down, maybe the problem can happen with bootstrap.

Comment: I want to display city (Foreign key field) with scroll to avoid the large scroll in the page (as in the photo)

Comment: @OmniaOsman Does the template code I provided with select tag is not working? What is it rendering?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252298/discussion-between-omnia-osman-and-sunderam-dubey).